# Targeting specific Dynamics 365 "App" in Outlook Add In

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm currently working on a Dynamics 365 instance and I'm investigating the feasibility of using the Outlook add in. In Dynamics, we are using the "Apps" functionality to separate out the different business areas of our application and more specifically, provide a customised, cut-down Sitemap.

The first problem that I've encountered is that it doesn't seem like it's possible to target a specific "App" in the Outlook add in, so the folders that are shown in the navigation pane in Outlook resemble that of the Sitemap for the default "Dynamics 365 - custom" app. To change the items that are displayed in the Outlook navigation pane, is the only option to change the Sitemap for the default "App", or am I missing something?

It seems like the development of the Outlook add in has fallen behind the rest of the functionality in Dynamics 365 to me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. And in fact, you're not wrong, development of new features for the add in stopped some time ago. As of the 9.0 release of D365, it will in fact [be deprecated.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/08/08/deprecation-of-dynamics-365-for-outlook/)